# Change detection behavior in Angular 9 related to animations

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I have an 'image flipper' component that fades between two images using animations.

It stopped updating properly when updating to Angular 9.0.0 - interestingly both with or without Ivy enabled.

The component is an `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` component, so of course I would expect to have to call `ChangeDetectorRef` for certain undetectable changes.

The full code isn't relevant but the callback function is something like this:

```
flipperDone(event: AnimationEvent)
{
    // when image has faded out...
    if (event.toState == "void")
    {
        // look to see if a new image is pending
        if (this.nextImage) 
        { 
            // if so display it...
            // (it will fade in via animation trigger)
            this.currentImage = this.nextImage;
            this.nextImage = undefined;

            // was not previously needed before Angualar 9 - why?
            // this._cdr.detectChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

`currentImage` is just a regular property referenced by the template, so of course I need to call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` - and that fixes it.

**However** this worked just fine before Angular 9 and I want to understand why - to make sure I don't make the same mistake elsewhere.

The documentation says:

> Components are normally marked as dirty (in need of rerendering) when
>   inputs have changed or events have fired in the view. Call this method
>   to ensure that a component is checked even if these triggers have not
>   occurred.

So that's a clue that maybe something isn't firing that did before. I don't *raise* any events in the component (no `@Output`).

So was there a change in the way animation events happen in Angular 9? Or ChangeDetection in general? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
Make sure you're firing the animation callback inside the NgZone.

For example if you're waiting for animation to finish and then use the default non-angular onfinish handler like this:

```
// example code from my directive

@Output()
animationFinished: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

startAnimation(): void {
  const animation = this.element.nativeElement.animate(...);

  animation.onfinish = () => {
    this.animationFinished.emit();
  };
}
```

The code won't run inside the NgZone and thus will not affect angular views. You need to wrap it in NgZone.run() function like this to make angular be aware of it:

```
animation.onfinish = () => {
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    this.animationFinished.emit();
  });
};
```

My original answer also works but elevating the solution closer to the cause of the problem feels like a better approach.

**Original answer:**
I ran into this today (Angular 10 btw) and my theory is that animation callback fires outside of NgZone. My setup was ChangeDetection.OnPush + Observables in the view and even though I updated my values using .next() on those observables (which definitely should run the change detection and refresh the view), nothing really happened until I fired the change detection manually by running ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() or by clicking somewhere in the page.

What I did was inject NgZone in the component and run the code inside of NgZone.run(), which did the trick for me and the view started working as expected.

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone){}

flipperDone(event: AnimationEvent) {
  // your 'if' logic
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    // your code to update variables to make angular be aware of the changes
  });
}
```

If there's a single view you're trying to update, running cdr.detectChanges() is imo perfectly fine. In my case it broke multiple views (I was emitting updated values through the service into multiple components) and implementing manual change detection everywhere felt just wrong.